# Different components on one page in Joomla?

Tags: joomla

Der All,

As I understood components in joomla are the body of the page and each request represents one component. Is it also possible to show two or more components on one page? Means I.e. Text and a contact form?

Thanks

Comment: No, you need to show one of those in a module instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try have a look at the 'Components Anywhere' extension from NoNumber.nl

This system plugin allow you to place components where you prefer, and "simulate" more components in one page so to say.
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/embed-a-include/25776

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. The component displayed is determined by the option variable in the request url. Every joomla call has to call a single component. You can modify the output by using:

- Modules: these are usually connected to a menu item, but can also be displayed by calling them directly from the component or template.
- Plugins: these are usually used to modify the output from components or modules.
- frame / iframe: you could also display output from a second component in a frame, for example using the iframe module.